# Running Scala Maven Project

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea

I am a scala beginner, and was running a starter project on Maven and using IntelliJ as IDE.

This is the link to project on github which I am using [Github project](https://github.com/jesperdj/scala-maven-example) and I compiled the project against OpenJDK8.

The HelloJava class runs successfully, however, when I try running the HelloScala class I come across the following error:

java -cp scala-maven-example-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.jesperdj.example.HelloScala

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Function0
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Function0
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 7 more
```

Comment: You may need to append the Scala runtime package in `-cp` param while running `java`.

Comment: oh. I tried that and it works. If you put up a proper answer, I will select as correct. Thanks!

Comment: I guess your question title was more on running Scala on Intellij?

Comment: @sudeepgupta90 I posted a slightly detailed answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala has its own runtime libraries above JVM. A compiled Scala `.class` has `import`ed some classes from Scala runtime libraries. When you try to run a Scala `.class` file, you need to append the Scala runtime to the `classpath`.

If you are running inside IntelliJ IDEA, the Scala Plugin will automatically do this, but when you run `java` from command line, you should do this yourself.

If you are using Maven, then you can add a `<plugin>`. From [Scala Docs -> Scala with Maven -> Creating a Jar](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/scala-with-maven.html#creating-a-jar):

> ```
> <build>
>     ...
>     <plugins>
>         ...
>         <plugin>
>             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>             <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
>             <version>2.4</version>
>             <configuration>
>                 <descriptorRefs>
>                     <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
>                 </descriptorRefs>
>                 <archive>
>                     <manifest>
>                         <mainClass>com.your-package.MainClass</mainClass>
>                     </manifest>
>                 </archive>
>             </configuration>
>             <executions>
>                 <execution>
>                     <phase>package</phase>
>                     <goals>
>                         <goal>single</goal>
>                     </goals>
>                 </execution>
>             </executions>
>         </plugin>
>     </plugins>
> </build>
> ```
>
> After adding this, mvn package will also create [artifactId]-[version]-jar-with-dependencies.jar under target. *Note: this will also **copy the Scala library into your Jar**. This is normal. Be careful that your dependencies use the same version of Scala, or you will quickly end up with a massive Jar.*

Comment: I was thinking more about this, and one more follow up. What can I do in my pom to basically include the scala runtime with the jar?

Comment: @sudeepgupta90 Add a plugin, see [Scala Docs -> Scala with Maven -> Creating a Jar](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/scala-with-maven.html#creating-a-jar).

Answer (score -1):

To run your programs on Intellij you need to install scala sdk along with JDK.

Once you have scala SDK in your Intellij classpath you are good to go with scala coding.

Answer (score -1):

Tick the checkbox 'include dependencies with "Provided" scope' under: 'Run\Debug Configurations'.
(Helps if yours is a maven project and you added the 'scala-library' dependency scope as 'Provided')
['Run\Debug Configurations'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htUD0.png)